# Aborting a JavaScript setTimeout function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The title may be misleading, but it's essentially what I need to accomplish.

I have an AJAX "Loading" text that I want to update if the server has taken more than 15 seconds to respond.

Here is the code:

```
$(".loader").html('Loading');
$(".loader").show();
setTimeout(function () {
    if ($('.loader').is(":visible")) {
        $(".loader").html('Click <a href="javascript:location.reload()">here</a> to reload.</span>');
    }
}, 15000);
```

Is there a better approach? When I eventually call `$(".loader").hide();` I want the `setTimeout` counter to be aborted. Is it possible?

Comment: Click https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.clearTimeout

Answer (score 5):

Sure. `setTimeout` returns a value you can pass to `clearTimeout` in order to stop timeout.

```
var handle = setTimeout(function () {
    alert("Oh noes, I ran!")
}, 5000)

clearTimeout(handle)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [clearTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.clearTimeout) function:

```
$(".loader").html('Loading');
$(".loader").show();
var timerId= setTimeout(function () {
    if ($('.loader').is(":visible")) {
        $(".loader").html('Click <a href="javascript:location.reload()">here</a> to reload.</span>');
    }
}, 15000);

$(".stop").click(function () {
    clearTimeout(timerId);
    $(".loader").html("done");
});
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KaNUP/

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend to make a shorter period (1 sec) and increment counter inside function you call. Then you can exit on successfull load or counter threshold, whichever comes earlier.

Comment: `setTimeout` != `setInterval`, and a counter would _either_ require a closure (which is overkill in this case) or a global variable, which is _evil_, in any case

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I'm aware about differences between those function. And I did, what I proposed before. And this is not a place, where you argue, whether global variables or `goto` operator or `eval()` is evil. Every tool suites it's task.

Comment: Aw come on... spite Down-vote? really? I didn't even DV your answer, but I just commented because I can't stand DV's whithout explanation... I just wanted to help you understand why some people might find your approach counter-productive or even _"bad practice"_. PS: When it comes to `eval` being evil: there is no discussion now that `JSON.parse` has been implemented in all browsers... I've written code for 9 years, 4 of which professionally, and I've never _ever_ needed `eval`...